# asp.net core webapi JWT validation using authorization filter and JWKS

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, auth0

I am writing an webapi using .net core 6. It need to validate user Authorization JWT token using Authorisation filter and JWKS (keys). May I have any example. I have search google and lots of example are using middleware.

I would like to use Authorisation filter + JWKS

Token header contain below

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  **"kid": "asdfb6T82zfdfdfJwc2eruee"**
}
```

Please any sample code, example would be excellent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with jwks and I tried with jwt token and validate the token in filter  as below:

```
public class JwTFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
       

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var jwt = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
            
            var validateParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() 
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1234567890123456")),
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:5000",
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "http://localhost:5001",
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
            };

            var valiresult = ValidateToken(jwt, validateParameters);
            
            
            if (valiresult == false)
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                context.Result = new JsonResult(new errmessage() { statuecode = "401", err = "Auth Failed" });
            }
        }
        private static bool ValidateToken(string token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            try
            {
                tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out var validatedToken);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
    }
    public class errmessage
    {
        public string statuecode { get; set; }
        public string err { get; set; }
    }
```

In startup class:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add<JwTFilter>();
            });
```

The ResulT:
[image]

**Update:**
Is it what you want?

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                var access_token = context.Request.Headers.Authorization?.Parameter; 
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(access_token))
                {
                    //401
                    context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    context.Result = new JsonResult(new errmessage() { statuecode = "401", err = "Auth Failed" });
                }
                else
                {
                    //access the public key
                    var httpclient = new HttpClient();
                    var jwtKey = httpclient.GetStringAsync(somejwksendpoint).Result;
                    //chache jwks
                    var Ids4keys = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ids4Keys>(jwtKey);
                    var jwk = Ids4keys.keys;
                    var parameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    { 
                        ValidIssuer = issUrl,
                        IssuerSigningKeys = jwk,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidAudience = apiName
                    };
                    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    //validate
                    var vali = handler.ValidateToken(access_token, parameters, out var _);
                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                context.Result = new JsonResult(new errmessage() { statuecode = "401", err = "Auth Failed" });
            }
        }
```

.....

```
public class Ids4Keys
    {
        public JsonWebKey[] keys { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. really appreciate it. However, I would like to use jwks and automatic download or caching

Comment: How can I do intergration test or unit test on Authorization filter?

Comment: I think you could  do uint test  on filter follow the blog  https://makolyte.com/aspdotnet-core-how-to-unit-test-an-action-filter/, and I've updated my answer concerned with jwks

Comment: Hi Ruikai, Thanks for updating. unit test is for action filter not authorization filter. I have been searching for two days and NO LUCK. please advice

Comment: I've answered your question about unittest in your another case:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72200846/authorization-filter-test-failed-webapi